# In electron transport system the final acceptor of proton is?

Tags: cellular-respiration, respiration

My lecture notes say that the answer to this is inorganic phosphate  (iP)..and the question is about proton not electron so the answer can't be oxygen. But I don't understand how is the answer iP

Comment: Hint: what's the overall chemical formula for respiration?

Comment: I still didn't get it..how is the answer iP?

Comment: Let’s see . . . loss of electrons is oxidation, and gain of electrons is reduction.  Respiration involves oxidation of carbon, and oxygen is the terminal electron acceptor in this process.  So carbon is oxidized, and oxygen is reduced.  And in the process the electron transport chain generates a proton motive gradient to generate ATP.  The Hydrogen ions (protons) move across the membrane, but do they need an acceptor?